# Parsing JSON from PHP in Swift 4

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I'm getting an error when loading JSON from a PHP output page using Swift 4.

*Note: The PHP script has been checked and is working fine*

```
let myUrl = URL(string: "http://localhost/swift/signin_up/login.php");
var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error!)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("response = \(response!)")
        print("==================================")
        //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {
                print(parseJSON)
            }
        } catch {
            print(" error:\(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

I get this error message from Xcode:

> error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

When I changed options to:

```
options: [.mutableContainers, .allowFragments]
```

I get this error message:

> error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

This is the PHP output I tested:

```
{"id":"1","email":"aa","password":"aa"}
```

Comment: When you get some error, please include the error message at least.

Comment: You can edit your own question.

Comment: I guess your php server is returning some sort of error, what do you get if you put `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))` before the line `let json = ...` ?

Comment: i replace a code with above and get message error{error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
@OOPer

Comment: `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))` would never output such message and I never suggested any sort of _replace_. Are you reading my comment?

Comment: Are you sure that it's supposed to be a POST request? This error indicates that the received data is not JSON (it's probably an HTML error). `.mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift, don't pass this parameter at all. And do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use native type `[String:Any]`. And dispatching the data task to the main thread is pointless, too, because it creates its own **background** thread anyway.

Comment: I am thankful for your interest in my question , Finally i found my error that i using UTF8 general_ci instead of utf8 encode-ci in my database server when i replaced the charset the code work correctly:@vadian

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when you set character_set in database server choose
(utf8_unicode_ci) to get correct json format when using

```
json_encode(//json variable);
```

in php